# bootstrap dropdown doesn't work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/Cwf4W/10/

there's my code I can't seem to get the bootstrap drop down menu to work, any help? I'm pretty sure I've got all the js right and the css too, I've been looking for awhile now :o

```
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="position: static;">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
              <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".subnav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </a>
              <a class="brand" href="#">Project Stalk</a>
              <div class="nav-collapse subnav-collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Settings <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Account settings</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Privacy settings</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-search pull-left" action="">
                  <input type="text" class="search-query span2" placeholder="Search">
                </form>
                <ul class="nav pull-right">
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
          </div><!-- /navbar-inner -->
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks right, but several javascript files including http://www.sieuphan.com/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js return an error-404

The development console shows these errors clearly (e.g in Chrome "View > Developer > Javascript console")

Comment: Oh, Thanks so much for pointing that out, I'm kinda a noobie, so I just use notepad++ and I don't really know much debugging :) just experimenting around. http://www.sieuphan.com/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js  shoulda been http://www.sieuphan.com/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js


thank you very much!

Comment: @SieuPhan It's worth keeping the javascript console open, even if just to check for error messages!